# html / code to add price in a specific block?

Tags: price, static-block, code

I've tried multiple snippets of code to add an item price to a specific block without success.

On the example item page : https://fixlcdscreens.com/default/catalog/product/view/id/10234/s/ACER-ASPIRE-V5-571-6868-15.6%22-Laptop-LCD-LED-Display-Screen/

I would like to add the product price in the right column block where I have put the text [INSERT PRICE HERE]

Can someone please help me achieve this in what you believe is the simplest way.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What is the righthand block called? without a little bit of code, cannot help. Also do you want to move the current price, or add a new one?

Answer (score 2):

Can you please try this :

```
$this->getPriceHtml($_product, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php
 $productBlock = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Product;
echo $productBlock->getPriceHtml($_product);
?>
```

**OR**

```
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
```